# Vue mixins unresolved function or method in template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, phpstorm, webstorm

I created a global function file:

```
module.exports = {
  methods: {
    t(key, replace = {}) {
      return 'test';
    }
  }
}
```

And I imported that to app with:

```
.mixin(require('./base'))
```

And this method works, but in my IDE (PhpStorm) is displaying error `Unresolved function or method t` in Vue files. How to display hints for functions like that?

Comment: what PhpStorm version is it? Please create a new ticket in [youtrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB), providing a minimal code sample the issue can be repeated with

Answer (score 0):

Yo need to use as `named` or `default` export.

```
export const myMixin = {
  methods: {
    t(key, replace = {}) {
      return 'test';
    }
  }
}
```

Then import like

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import { myMixin } from '..../myMixin.js';

Vue.mixin(myMixin);
```

Comment: it's not working, still undefined in template

Comment: Could you please elaborate. Not sure if your issue is related to mixins